# Rails Sub URI 403 Forbidden Errors when Deploying with Passenger for Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, symlink, http-status-code-403

I am trying to run Run the Server with the following configuration and am getting an error as shown below

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        #Web SERVER
        server {
            server_name 104.236.218.36;
            listen 80;
            root /var/www/noise/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        # API SERVER
        server {
            server_name 104.236.218.36;
            listen 3333;
            root /var/www/noise-api/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        #passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
        passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


# mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# }
```

**ERROR**

```
2015/02/02 06:16:06 [error] 13528#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/noise/public/" is forbidden, client: 122.178.204.27, server: 104.236.218.36, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", ho$
```

I came across this [Article](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/4-rails-sub-uri-403-forbidden-errors-when-deploying-with-passenger-for-nginx) but am not able to figure out how to apply the solution for my set up. i do not have a folder

```
root@99atoms-staging:/var/www/noise# cd /websites/
-bash: cd: /websites/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try your passenger_root with this `passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RVM then use this passenger_root and passenger_ruby:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby;
```

Then reload nginx server.

Comment: i had that settings before and it created more issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275747/nginx-passenger-rails-server-error

Comment: Yes in it passenger_root is different. For more detail look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04. It will help you.

Comment: i changed it based on the http://stackoverflow.com/a/16473722/155196 but i still get the same error.

Comment: 403 error means you don’t have permission to access that part of the web. Can you show me your app path and its permission?